# Database schema design strategy for pharmacy and drug prescriptions

Tags: sql-server, database-design, architecture, sql-server-2012, database-schema

I am in the process of designing a small database application for a health center in my local community. The health center can receive both In & Out-Patients.

The one area i am not sure of how best it should be implemented is how to bill the patient automatically from the drugs/medication they have be given. I don't want the user to type in the name and price of the drugs given to the patient. I want to automate it with a list of all available drugs and their **CURRENT** prices in a table so that the user just selects a drug from a list & i the software should be able to determine the total.

I also want to maintain the history of drugs over time. Some thing like drug **XXX** was selling at $1234 in January, $4567 in September, $12 in 2008. So if i am to print a receipt for a patient who visited in 2008, the patient should be billed at the rates of 2008 not the drug current rate.

I am just asking for some general guidance and suggestions on the best database schema of a scenario related to my problem description above.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a table of drugprices

```
DrugPriceID    DrugID   PriceStartDate    DrugPrice
1              1        1-1-2008          1234
2              1        1-9-2008          4567
```

which links to a table of drugs on `DrugID`.  The price applies until it is superseded by a new price.

A table of Patients, which links to a table of PatientOrders,

```
PatientOrderID PatientID OrderDate
5              3         4-5-2008
```

and a further table of OrderDrugs

```
OrderDrugID   PatientOrderID   DrugID
6             5                1
```

Comment: I have a problem with handling the unit of measure for a drug. Say for example a bottle of drug XXX might be shared across more than 1 patient. OR a patient's illness doesn't require the prescription of a full dose of a drug. Any idea how i can break the drug down to the lowest possible unit of measure.

Comment: @SQL.NETWarrior Do different prices apply for different doses? Is there a bulk discount?

Comment: Yes different prices apply for different doses & at the moment there is no bulk discount though tha is a great idea to implement as well.

Comment: Then you may want to expand drugprices to include a dosage, or if dosages are standard, add a dosage table and link to that.

Comment: And then bill at the dosage level?

Comment: That depends on the requirements, but log the prescription at the dosage level